# Persisting ArrayList<String> with ORMLite in Android

Tags: java, android, collections, arraylist, ormlite

When trying to persist the class `Goods` with **ORMLite**, I don't know how to persist `componentList` here. I have found a similar question [Persisting a Collection class with ORMLite in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272155/persisting-a-collection-class-with-ormlite-in-android), but it seems not pointing the way to solve the problem.

```
public class Goods extends Object implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7560219283718464481L;
...
    public ArrayList<String> componentList;

    public String getComponentList(){
        return componentList;
    }
    public void setComponentList(ArrayList<String> componentList){
        this.componentList = componentList;
    }
...

}
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441595/how-to-store-the-arraylist-in-ormlite-database/31598771#31598771 for an easier solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have found a similar question Persisting a Collection class with ORMLite in android, but it seems not pointing the way to solve the problem.

Unfortunately, it's the only way that ORMLite has to store a collection of related items.  In your case you need a `Component` class that has something like:

public class Component {
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
    private Goods goods;
    ...

And then your `Goods` class would be:

```
public class Goods {
    @ForeignCollectionField
    private Collection<Component> components;
    ...
```

To assign components to an entry in the `Goods` table, you would create an `Component` entry and set the `goods` field, and `dao.create(...)` it.

Take a look at the [foreign-collection docs](http://ormlite.com/docs/foreign-collection) which may provide more information.
To quote from them:

> A foreign collection allows you to add a collection of orders on the account table. Whenever an Account object is returned by a query or refreshed by the DAO, a separate query is made over the order table and a collection of orders is set on the account. All of the orders in the collection have a corresponding foreign object that matches the account. For example:

```
public class Account {
    …
    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = false)
    ForeignCollection<Order> orders;
    …
}
```

> In the above example, the @ForeignCollectionField annotation marks that the orders field is a collection of the orders that match the account. The field type of orders must be either ForeignCollection or Collection – no other collections are supported because they are much heavier with many methods to support.